# Matrix transpose $A^TA=0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a matrix.

$$A^TA=0 \iff A=0$$How can I prove this?

Please help me.

Comment: Hint: Compute the top left element of the product.

Comment: To avoid confusion, note, that the left $0$ is the zero-matrix in $\mathrm{Mat}(ℝ, n×n)$, while the right $0$ is in $ℝ$. Furthermore this will not work in $ℂ$ as-is – you’ll need to take the conjugate matrix $A^*$ instead of the transpose $A^T$ there.

Comment: For more information, you know we have trace norm which is defined by $\|A\|_{trace}=trace\sqrt{AA^*}$ thus if $AA^*=0$  then
$$\|A\|_{trace}=trace\sqrt{AA^*}=trace\sqrt{0}=0\Rightarrow A=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's to get you started. Suppose that $A = [a_{ij}]$, where $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.

We need to figure out what a typical entry of $A^TA$ looks like.

To find entry $(i,j)$ in $A^TA$, you need to calculate the dot product of the $i$th row of $A^T$ with the $j$th column of $A$ - but the $i$th row of the transpose is exactly equal to the $i$th column of $A$, meaning that the entry we are looking for is

$$\sum_{k=1}^m a_{ki}a_{kj}$$

This number is equal to $0$ for all $(i,j)$. What happens in particular for $i=j$, and what are the consequences?

Comment: The first thing you should do is look at that product for a 2 by 2 or 3 by 3 matrix.  It should very quickly occur to you that the diagonal elements of the product are sum of squares!

Comment: Or you can just consider trace($A^{T}A$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson you're right, but my guess was that the OP isn't yet aware that $$||A|| = \text{trace}(\sqrt{A^TA})$$ constitutes a norm.

Answer (score 1):

We know that rank$(A^TA)$=rank$(AA^T)$=rank$(A)$.

Here if $AA^T=0$, then rank$(AA^T)$=rank$(A)$=$0$

$\implies A=0$

And if $A=0$ then other part is trivially true.

Comment: Assuming the first statement seems to be assuming something as strong as what is being asked in the question.